# Mac address conversion to bytes

Tags: python, networking, byte, data-conversion, binascii

I am trying to convert a mac address in hex like this: `00453645f200`
to a Mac address in bytes like this:
`x00\x45\x36\x45\xf2\x00`

But if I use `binascii.unhexlify`, the result is like this:
`b'\x00E6E\xf2\x00'`. How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The python interpreter will re-format the byte string `b'x00\x45\x36\x45\xf2\x00'` to `b'\x00E6E\xf2\x00'` automatically:

```py
>>> b'x00\x45\x36\x45\xf2\x00'
b'x00E6E\xf2\x00'
```

You can however, print the hexadecimal representation of each byte via:

```py
address = 0x00453645f200
for byte in address.to_bytes(6, 'big'):
    print(hex(byte))
```